# Documenting GraphQL short-hand model

Tags: graphql

How does one document the model, using GraphQL shorthand notation?

`type User {
  name: String
}`

Say I want to add a description for the type/attribute above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptions come in the form of comments:

```
# Someone who uses something
type User {
  # How we refer to the user
  name: String
}
```

Those should be added as descriptions to the schema generated from this notation.